# Canvas HTML 5 zoom containing dynamic figures

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have wasted my 2 day for searching my issue on google but didn't get any clue. Actually i have working code for drawing circle,square,line on mouse down and up event on canvas(this drawing is dynamically drawn on canvas).Now i want to zoom in canvas that contain this figure randomly.

When i tried this, i came to know that... there is requirement to redraw the figure after scaling of canvas.Is there any way to to do this in simple way ?

Is there any method in canvas that maintain all information related to drawn figures ?

Can i draw this figures in respective proportion after zoom ?

Please help me...Any clue or any code snippet that help me to work further.
Thankssss you for any help.....

I have following code snippet that contain one curve which called again and again while zoom.But this figure is static so everytime coordinates are same. but in my case figures coordinates changing as figure changing.

```
function draw(scale, translatePos){
                var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

                // clear canvas
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                context.save();
                context.translate(translatePos.x, translatePos.y);
                context.scale(scale, scale);
                context.beginPath(); // begin custom shape
                context.moveTo(-119, -20);

                context.bezierCurveTo(-159, 0, -159, 50, -59, 50);
                context.bezierCurveTo(-89, -95, -139, -80, -119, -20);

        context.closePath(); // complete custom shape
                context.fill();
                context.stroke();
                context.restore();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvases are just pixels, and the drawing methods just set the colours of those pixels.

If you want to *correctly* rescale primitive shapes, you'll have to remember what shapes you've drawn, and redraw them from scratch when you resize.

If you can, use the canvas's transformation matrix support to handle the scaling for you - that'll avoid having to recalculate any coordinates yourself.

Comment: Thanks Alnitak for reply,
       i got your point.Can you give me any snippet of code for canvas's trasformation matrix.that will help me to move further. 
Thanks for help ..

Comment: you're already using the transformation matrix in your code above - I was just suggesting that you take advantage of the canvas's built-in ability to scale from one coordinate system to another when you resize

Comment: But my figures co-ordinates are not fixed.Everytime they are changing if drawing change. Above code is for curve having this fixed co-ordinate.I'm drawing figure at runtime and want to zoom that figure.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you "fix" any coordinates.  For example, if you zoom in by two, you can wrap your whole redraw with `.scale()` to map your _existing_ coordinates so that when you redraw the figure it gets bigger even though you're passing the _same_ coordinates.  You would also need to `.translate()` to specify the origin of the zoom.

Comment: I'm not getting you. for redraw figure i want previous co-ordinate that i do not have. How can i wrap whole redraw with .scale() ??

Comment: @Sumeet that's the whole point - "_you'll have to remember what shapes you've drawn_" _**including the coordinates**_

Comment: Means canvas not giving any method to redraw whole things while zoom. 
        i'm clear with this now.
Do you any suggestion/clue/snippet of code for me to go further ? 
Means how to store co-ordinate or figures i'm drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Have One More Argument Zoom in draw function and call draw function once again when you want to zoom in. Pass the value that how much you wanna zoom e.g. 2x and multiply all values according e.g. for 2x, multiply all values with 2.

Comment: This bezierCurveTo is static.I'm adding dynamic figures (like arc,sqaure,line using mouse up and down events ) with changing co-ordinates. So i want to zoom and redraw this figures after zoom.

Comment: @Sumeet i have never used canvases just gave an idea to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear on what you are asking. I think this is what you are asking.

In an application using canvas, figures such as squares, circles and lines can be drawn by a user using the mouse. The user has drawn a square and a circle on the canvas. The user should be able to re-size the square, making it larger or smaller, without changing the size of the circle. The user should be able to re-set the square to its original size. Is this possible just using the properties and methods of the Canvas object?

Is this what you are asking?

If not try describing what you want a user of your application to be able to do.

Comment: No.. I don't want to re size actual figures,but i want only zoom to figure ,means figure automatically get close to screen.

 Actually i'm drawing figure on canvas using mouse events. 
like below link example 

but this contain  beziercurve as constant co-ordinate and drawing figure having dynamically changing co-ordinate which may vary userwise.Lastly this figure should zoom like below examles link

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-scaling-a-drawing-with-plus-and-minus-buttons/#comment-19246